# Couldn't get array values in Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

The JSON model:

[image: If you want to know the JSON Model here it is]

I am using Alamofire but I couldn't get the elements of the "types" array. I am using the following code:

```
if let Types = mainData["types"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
    print(Types.count)
    print(Types)
}
```

Comment: Use this `if let Types = mainData["types"] as? [String] {
    print(Types.count)
    print(Types)
}`

Comment: First use the code `print(mainData)` and see how datas are modeled in it, If you would like put the result here to get to the answer of your problem.

Comment: `types` is in a array `data` in the root object and in Swift 3+ a JSON dictionary is always `[String:Any]` however the type of `types` is `[String]`

Comment: @ReinierMelian how can i access the values of types array?